# Excel Vba stops excution after deleting sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I have written a code to delete a particular sheet. After execution of that delete sheet macro, excel macro stopped execution. It didnt execute futher..

Here is my code..

```
Sub CopyAcross()
Dim sheetName As String
sheetName = "Master_Base"
If WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then
 DeleteSheet (sheetName)
End If
MsgBox "Debug"

Workbooks("Master_Base.csv").Sheets("Master_Base").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Copy of    test.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")
End Sub 

Sub DeleteSheet(strSheetName As String)
' deletes a sheet named strSheetName in the active workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(strSheetName).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Can any one help on this,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works just fine for me

Comment: I have executed line by line by setting breakpoint at copyAcross API .it stops exactly at Sheets(strSheetName).Delete.

Comment: remove `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and see what message do you get, if any?

Comment: I have removed it. Still it stops at the same point.

Comment: What exactly happens? Does it give a message? does that line get highlighted?

Comment: If you are working with multiple workbooks, then try this as well `Thisworkbook.Sheets(strSheetName).Delete`

Comment: Nope Still its stops its execution at the same point. Let me explain you the use case. I need to copy a sheet from Masterbase.csv to active workbook. First time it works fine. Second time it copies the data by creating new sheet. Like this its keep on going. I dint want the to happen. So i thought to delete the sheet if already presents. But that is stopping exactly while deleting the sheet. it didnt throw any error messages nor highlighted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61025/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-kayle).

Comment: Do  you have any event code in the workbook, or any UDFs that you use in conditional formatting?

Comment: Is the macro saved in a module, the workbook, or an individual sheet?

Comment: @DennisSuter yes. It is saved module.

Comment: @Rory Event code means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with multiple workbooks, use objects. Else your code **MAY** work with the wrong workbook/worksheet

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub CopyAcross()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook

    '~~> The workbook from where the code is running
    Set wbO = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Here you open the csv
    Set wbI = Workbooks.Open("E:\OPM\OPM Sheet\Master_Base.csv")

    '~~> This will delete the sheet if it exists
    '~~> no need to check if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbO.Sheets("Master_Base").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> The csv will always have 1 sheet
    '~~> so no need providing a name
    wbI.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=wbO.Worksheets("Sheet3")
End Sub
```

Comment: When i am executing from different workbook Code works perfectly fine. There is no break in execution. Thank you siddharth. :)

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same issue, on a Windows 7 computer with Excel version 16.0.10730.20264 32-bit, the code ran fine without issue. However, on a Windows 10 computer with the same Excel install version, the macro would immediately stop execution following the Sheets.Delete line.

I found that this was only happening where I was attempting to manipulate a workbook that contained VBA code, that I had opened during the macro.

The issue is caused by the macro security settings on the computer. If you set Automation Security to Low before opening the workbook, you should no longer get the error:

Use the code:

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the same problem and your solution works like a charm. In my case AutomationSecurity was set to msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable, after change to Low everything is OK.

Comment: I had the same problem... i first tried switching it to `msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` but that didn't work... it had to be `msoAutomationSecurityLow`. Another bug.